# No Visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'setText:'

Tags: objective-c

I tried to extract some values from a core data entry and assign them to NSStrings. So far my code looks like this:

```
#import "CopyToClipViewController.h"

@interface CopyToClipViewController ()

@end

@implementation CopyToClipViewController
@synthesize device;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (self.device) {
        NSString *namevalue;
        NSString *versionvalue;
        NSString *companyvalue;
        [namevalue setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [versionvalue setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"version"]];
        [companyvalue setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"company"]];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am receiving the error, No Visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'setText:' for all three lines that try to set data to the NSStrings. Any ideas for solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just write: companyvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"company"]; You  can not use setText on the String itself

Comment: Read the message.  You are doing "setText" on something that you've told the compiler is an NSString.  (In this case it's fairly obvious where.)

Comment: Read the error. You're trying to use a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: (`setText` is a method of UILabel and several other classes, but not a method of NSString.)

Comment: Thanks to all. I used @user1567896 solution and it worked. Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: vote to close: off topic: minimal understanding required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write:

```
companyvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"company"];
```

You can not use setText on a NSString